# Update error Xubuntu 13.04

Tags: command-line, 13.04, updates, kernel, dpkg

When I try to install or remove items I'm unable to do so due to 3 programs that aren't fully installed. Ive tried removing them and reinstalling but no luck when I tried to configure I got this:-

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
Setting up linux-image-extra-3.8.0-23-generic (3.8.0-23.34) ...
Running depmod.
update-initramfs: deferring update (hook will be called later)
Examining /etc/kernel/postinst.d.
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 3.8.0-23-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.8.0-23-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 3.8.0-23-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.8.0-23-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.8.0-23-generic

gzip: stdout: No space left on device
E: mkinitramfs failure cpio 141 gzip 1
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-3.8.0-23-generic with 1.
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools exited with return code 1
Failed to process /etc/kernel/postinst.d at /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-extra-3.8.0-23-generic.postinst line 1010.
dpkg: error processing linux-image-extra-3.8.0-23-generic (--configure):
subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-image-generic:
linux-image-generic depends on linux-image-extra-3.8.0-23-generic; however:
Package linux-image-extra-3.8.0-23-generic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing linux-image-generic (--configure):
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-generic:
linux-generic depends on linux-image-generic (= 3.8.0.23.39); however:
Package linux-image-generic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing linux-generic (--configure):
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
linux-image-extra-3.8.0-23-generic
linux-image-generic
linux-generic
```

How would I go about fixing this problem? I know it says no space left but I only updated a while ago and don't have any files as I just browse the internet and that error came after trying to update.

Comment: `gzip: stdout: No space left on device` is the key, do you have enough space in all the partitions?

Answer (score -1):

If the terminal isnt your speed, try to run the computer janitor in ubuntu tweak.  It will clean out /boot and many more...  Follow directions here to install http://www.webupd8.org/2013/04/download-ubuntu-tweak-084-now.html

If you are comfortable with the terminal or trying to learn more about linux, then follow the steps taken here: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1435818

Brought to you by google :)